# Unable to set permission for directory in Perl

Tags: perl, chmod, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory with name `mydir` in current path where I am executing the perl script using File::Path module.

Directory is being created if it is not already exists, but directory permission I am not able to set to `777`. y default its been setting permission as `755`.

Here is my code.

```
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);

if (! -d "mydir") {
    if (!make_path( "mydir", {
            verbose => 1,
            mode => 0777,
            owner => "vinod",
    })) {
            print  "Couldn't create dir\n";
            return -1;
    }
}
```

I want directory to be created with permission `0777`

Answer (score 1):

Use `chmod` instead of `mode` argument. Something like that:

```
make_path "mydir", {
            verbose => 1,
            chmod   => 0777,
            owner   => "vinod"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @miguel. Whatever permission you give inside ```chmod =>``` by default its creating with ```755```. If you do it manually it works. I was thinking whether it is something to do with OS version I am using?

Answer (score 0):

chmod value should be decimal, what you are using is octal. Try changing the value to 511

Comment: Octal 0777 and decimal 511 are equivalent once parsed.